# Using Stack Exchange to power a MediaWiki wiki

Tags: discussion

Wikis are great because they make information available. Stack Exchange is great because it makes asking questions easy. I'd like to see how the two can be put together, so that people can ask questions in a Stack Exchange-like format and the answers can easily be migrated into a wiki.

Is there a Stack Exchange-type extension available for MediaWiki?

I've seen [WordPress MediaWiki integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745). Ideally I'm looking for a introductory guide, also explaining some options.

Furthermore, I'm looking for people's experiences with this and their advice.

Comment: BTW - it's for a company environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the features of Stack Overflow for a company environment, take a look at [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Pekka - thanks, but I'm looking for an OpenSource (free, configurable) solution ideally.  BTW - we already have a wiki up-and-running so I'm not looking to replace it but enhance it.

Comment: @Mark I see. In that case, I would specify what aspects of your current wiki could use enhancement (say, the markdown editor for example.).

Comment: @Pekka - I'm not looking to enhance the wiki software itself - that's going well.  It is more about having a forum where people can ask and answer questions.  I like the rapid response nature of StackOverflow.  Then the responses can be used (possibly) to feed wiki content.

Comment: @Mark I see. In that case, I would recommend looking for an Open Source package  of some sort that is similar to SO's concept (there are some around, search for "Stack Overflow Clone" here on MSO) and to integrate it loosely with the Wiki (e.g. by adding a "Move this question to Wiki" button once a question is well answered.) I don't think you are going to find an integrated product that features a good Wiki, and SO style community functions out of the box.

Comment: @Pekka - that is what I am looking for, thanks.  I would vote this up but I don't have the reputation yet... (why don't the Stack Overflow implementations (standard and meta) share the reputation?!)

Comment: @Pekka / Down with ... now I have the rep I can vote your posts up... =:-)

Answer (score 2):

Umm... Stack Overflow already incorporates many wiki features. Earn enough reputation and you can edit anything, just like a wiki.

The main difference is that Stack Overflow allows a much greater sense of ownership for content, and so it only makes sense that it also requires a higher investment from users before granting editing privileges.

Comment: Are you saying that StackOverflow makes wikis obsolete?

I'm thinking of a company environment - the two would work well together, if properly integrated.

Comment: @Mark: The 2 *are* integrated. Also: you can associate your accounts on your profile page, accounts tab.

Comment: @Fretje - thanks for the great tip about associating accounts.  OK - you say the 2 are integrated. I wasn't aware of that (hence the question). So can you elaborate - what do you mean?

Comment: @Mark read my whole post again - StackOverflow already lets you do anything that a wiki does.  You just need more rep to do it, and for good reason.

Comment: @Mark: What Joel said. Once you hit 2K rep, you can edit almost anything on the site, hence wiki integration...

Comment: @Joel, @Fretje - thanks for the answers.  You seem to be implying that a wiki functionality is a subset of StackOverflow functionality.  But if I want to read, e.g. a C++ introductory article - I'll go to a wiki, not StackOverflow - right?

Comment: @Mark sure, but that has nothing to do with the StackOverflow engine.  A StackExchange site could certainly support things like introductory articles as-is; it's only community-enforced site policy that prevents it on StackOverflow.com and company.  Your "company environment" could choose to encourage that kind of thing rather than suppress it.

Comment: @Joel - OK, I think I'm beginning to understand.  It seems I have two options:
1. Abandon existing wiki and go to StackOverflow-like software.  This will involve porting existing data and new way of working for all - which seems an unrealistically large investment.
2. Use a StackOverflow-like interface to encourage feedback - my original idea.  I'm no closer to seeing how these two could be integrated.
Related - where can I find a good introduction to StackOverflow functionality?